# Apex class that inserts a new account named after an incoming parameter

Tags: apex, custom-controller

The Apex class must be called 'AccountHandler' and be in the public scope.
The Apex class must have a public static method called 'insertNewAccount'.
The 'insertNewAccount' method must accept an incoming string as a parameter, name the account after the parameter, insert it into the system and then return the account record.
I have tried this

```
public class AccountHandler {

    public static Account insertNewAccount(String Test) {
            Account acct = new Account(Name='Acme', Phone='(415)555-1212', NumberOfEmployees=100);
            insert acct;
       } 
        return acct;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at what the requirements are I would suggest you trying this code:

```
public class AccountHandler {
    public static Account insertNewAccount(String name) {
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = name;
        try {
            insert a;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

This method takes `name` string parameter and makes a new `Account`. Then it tries to insert it, but if insert fails then it returns `null`. If insert succeeds, it will return that account object.

Answer (score 2):

I agree almost totally with Novarg code, but I think you should also manage the case in which you insert an empty string (as suggested by the exercise).

`public class AccountHandler {`

```
   public static Account insertNewAccount (String accName){ 

   if(accName!=''){    
       try{
           Account a = new Account(Name=accName);
           insert a;
           System.debug('Bravo User5633! Account created');
           return a;
       } catch(Exception e){
           System.Debug('Account not created');
           return null;
       }
   } else {
       return null;
   }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the account creation statement as below

```
Account acct = new Account(Name=Test+ 'Acme', Phone='(415)555-1212', NumberOfEmployees=100);
```

Comment: The 'insertNewAccount' method must also accept an empty string, catch the failed DML and return null.

Comment: how to execute this

Comment: You mean another argument to the method?

Comment: DML errors will occur only if the record getting inserted contains any errors/missing mandatory details. For your case you have hardcoded it as 'Acme'. So this would not throw error, considering you're passing ''(blank string). But you will get error only if you're passing null. In this case you need not pass it to method, You can do validation even before calling the method.